# What is meant by bytesPerLine in QImage?

Tags: qt, qt4

What is mean by bytesPerLine in

```
QImage::QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, Format format )
```

In documentation it is mentioned as bytesPerLine specifies the number of bytes per line (stride).
I am not clear with its usage. Are width and bytesPerLine the same? Could anyone please explain it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

bytesperline means the number of bytes required by the image pixels in a given row.

to illustrate this consider the following code snippet...

```
int imageWidth = 800;
int imageHeight = 600;
int bytesPerPixel = 4; // 4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB
int format = QImage::Format_ARGB32; // this is the pixel format - check Qimage::Format enum type for more options
QImage image(yourData, imageWidth, imageHeight, imageWidth * bytesPerPixel, format);
```

Comment: bytesPerPixel = 1 for 8 bit Grayscale?